# Flatten comment's tree from Reddit

Tags: reddit, praw

I've been using praw (Reddit API wrapper in python) for sentiment analysis.

Is there a way to get all the comments as flattened text? I've understood that praw fetches comment objects that can be recursively iterated to obtain more comments using comment.replies, but they are still singular comments. Can't I get the entire conversation as one string?

If a thread has following structure -

```
comment1
  comment2
    comment3
    comment4
      comment5
  comment6
```

Then I'm expecting the following output

```
"comment1 -> comment2 -> comment3"
"comment1 -> comment2 -> comment4 -> comment5"
"comment1 -> comment6"
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you run into? Also your question is not clear, but if you are asking if there is already predefined function to get this, then no there isn't.

Comment: I can get the comments from praw as comment objects, no problem there.  Each comment object has a 'body' and 'replies' tag. I want to concatenate the body with all replies (and their replies ad infinitum) as shown above.

Comment: This is pretty straightforward recursion. Single function that appends current comment body to a parameter and then calls itself for every memeber in replies with current concentrated body and that particular member. Just edit the quesiton if you have any problem with code.

Comment: Yeah it's working, Thanks!